# Create/insert event (Google Calendar API v3) via HTTP Post > "400: Missing end time"

Tags: api, url, post, google-calendar-api, filemaker

I am using FileMaker to interact with the Google Calendar API. I have managed to authorize my app, get a list of user's calendars and a list of events in those calendars and details for those events. However, I am having trouble creating events.

I make the following HTTP POST request. Header: Content-Type : application/json, Authorization : Bearer access_token

https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/**********@gmail.com/events?{"attachments":[{"fileUrl":""}],"attendees":[{"email":"***********@gmail.com"}],"end":{"dateTime":"2017-08-20T13:00:00-05:00"},"reminders":{"useDefault":true},"start":{"dateTime":"2017-08-20T12:00:00-05:00"},"summary":"Test Event"}

I receive the following JSON error response:

```
{
    "error": 
    {
        "errors": 
            [
                {
                    "domain": "global",
                    "reason": "required",
                    "message": "Missing end time."
                }
            ],
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Missing end time."
    }
}
```

It appears that this is a pretty common error that people run into. However it looks like most having this problem are using frameworks for which there are libraries that Google Calendar API supports. I've tried to pick out the fix from some of the posts on stackoverflow and elsewhere concerning these other frameworks and apply them to my FileMaker / HTTP GET/POST setup to no avail.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having the same problem building my own http request.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [this](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) instead.

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events
```

And supply the `calendarId` according to what the parameter requires

> Calendar identifier. To retrieve calendar IDs call the
>   [calendarList.list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list) method. If you want to access the primary calendar
>   of the currently logged in user, use the "primary" keyword.

Comment: I may be missing something, but I believe that is how my HTTP POST was written in my original post. The API doesn't like something about the "Event Resource" that I included in the request body. Do you know what the "Event Resource" / http request body should look like?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{email}/events' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer {access_token}' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
--data-raw '{`enter code here`
  "summary": "Google I/O 2015",
  "location": "800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103",
  "description": "A chance to hear more about Google'\''s developer products.",
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00",
    "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles"},
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00",
    "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles"
  },
  "recurrence": [
    "RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2"
  ],
  "attendees": [
    {"email": "lpage@example.com"},
    {"email": "sbrin@example.com"}
  ],
  "reminders": {
    "useDefault": false,
    "overrides": [
      {"method": "email", "minutes": 24},
      {"method": "popup", "minutes": 10}
    ]
  }
}'
```